# How to configure Rails app for deployment to Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby

I have a Rails app that I package as a war file for deploying to Tomcat using Warbler. And it works, but the problem is I don't know how to configure the runtime properties like `secret_key_base`. I use the standard setup of using `secrets.yml`, with production variables coming from environment variables. But I don't know how to set the variables while still keeping them out of source control.

Ideally I'd still like to be able to deploy the war file automatically, by just dropping it into the `webapps/` directory, but I suppose I could edit the server config file? Or is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

either do it the same way as you would in a Rails server ... let it read from `ENV` (of course you will need to make sure Tomcat has the environment variable set).

alternatively you can set it in a *web.xml* if you're packaging and than do a `$servlet_context.getAttribute('foo')` in **secrets.yml** ... or read it from a file location that only the server's tomcat username can access etc.

sky is the limit here - you basically need to decide what fits your deployments the best.